# How to avoid Selenium webdriver from being detected as bot?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, data-mining, chrome-web-driver

I have used selenium web driver to scrape a website in python. The issue is When I open the website in the Chrome browser there is no captcha. But when I open it in the selenium (using chrome web driver), The captcha appeared.

I have used vim to replace the **$cdc_** with a random variable but no success.
Here is the code.

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
options.add_argument('--start-fullscreen')
options.add_argument('--single-process')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument("--incognito")
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= "chromedriver.exe", options=options)


driver.get("https://muckrack.com/media-outlets")
time.sleep(20)
```